# print specific line from multiple files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a collection of 5000+ files and I just want to create an `output.txt` file which contains the 27th line of all the files, along with their filenames.
What I got from the internet is picking specific line from a single file using `awk` or `sed` commands, such as:
`$sed -n 27p *.txt >>output.txt`

for example my files in a directory are:

```
log_1.txt
log_2.txt
log_3.txt
log_4.txt
.
.
.
```

I want the 27th line of each file with its file name in front or behind of the printed line in the new `output.txt` file.

Comment: oops.. so much editing.
Thanx arzyfex

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 awk 'FNR==27 {print FILENAME, $0}' *.txt >output.txt
```

- `FILENAME` is built-in awk variable for current input file name
- `FNR` refer to line number of current file
- `$0` means whole line

Comment: Thanx man
this was much better for me.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is :

```
for i in * ; do echo -n $i" : "  ; head -n 27 "$i" | tail -n 1 ; done > output.txt
```

Comment: I set up a file with 500 million 100 byte records and for that case, this version works fastest for me at 1m2.582s followed by the sed version at 1m20.81s and awk at 2m14.756s

Comment: Plus this is more flexible. If the logs g-zipped you can simply add in the loop the `zcat` command.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `for` loop:

```
{ for i in *.txt; do echo "$i : $(sed -n '27p' "$i")"; done ;} >output.txt
```

The `for` loop may be expensive as you have 5000+ files but given the current hardwares should not be a problem.

---

Faster way, quitting `sed` after line 27 *(thanks @Fiximan)*:

```
{ for i in *.txt; do echo "$i : $(sed -n '27p;q' "$i")"; done ;} >output.txt
```

Comment: Would you need a `'27p;q'` to be faster or will `sed` quit automatically after hitting line 27?

Comment: @Fiximan yes that will be quicker

Comment: @Fiximan That surely would..edited..thanks..

Comment: @Fiximan - sed would quit so quick that it won't print anything...

Answer (score 0):

Simple awk usage:

```
awk 'FNR==27 {print FILENAME,$0}' /path/to/files/log_*.txt > outfile.txt
```