# Pick random row from a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, random

How do I pick a random row of text from a file?

Comment: Should "any row" be interpreted as "a random row" specifically, or are you just looking for the top or bottom row? This question is _trivial_ to solve. I'm just a bit confused by the haphazard "any row".

Comment: Just any random row

Comment: How random? `head -n 1 file` will give you the first row, `tail -n 1 file` will give you the last one.

Comment: Not the head and tail rows it can be any row ,suppose I have 100 rows ,the output should be like only one row out of that 100 rows(that one row can be from 1-100)

Comment: The question currently asks for "any row", but you _specifically want a random row_.  This is different from "any row".

Comment: The question is now a duplicate of [How to randomly sample a subset of a file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/108581) (with 1000 changed to 1). Or possibly of [Randomly draw a certain number of lines from a data file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/29709) (or both).

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326535/117549

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277242/print-specific-line-from-multiple-files

Comment: `n=$(wc -l <"$path"); head -$[(RANDOM<<15+RANDOM)%n] "$path"|tail -1` The distribution won't be perfectly level and it will see only the first billion lines of large textfiles. The location of the file should be in the `path` environment variable.